# Variance of a sample and normal distribution

Tags: variance, inference, sample, estimators

I'm a bit confused about the concept of estimating population variance through a sample. An exercise about theoretical vs empirical distribution of data asks to graphically represent the data of a row vector (they were the temperatures recorded daily for a month, with n=30) and to compare it with the theoretical distribution: I've run the Shapiro test in R to be sure that the date came from a normal population and I've got evidence of that. I plotted the data with the command "hist" in R and got an almost bell-shaped curve.

The problem occurs now: am I supposed to refer to the CLT? The exercise doesn't make any reference to the population mean, I do not have to study sample mean distribution (I know that it it normally distributed with mean the mean of the single random variable and variance the variance of the single random variable divided by n=30).

I also know that the sample deviance divided by (n-1) instead of n estimates the population variance without bias.

What I am supposed to do is to plot a curve in R on the histogram, and it should be a Gaussian curve (because of Shapiro test outcome): but what are its parameters? Or, what is the variance parameter? Is it the unbiased sample variance or the variance divided by n=30?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to plot the *sample distribution* or the estimated *population distribution* from the data? In the first case, this can be done by plotting the histogram along with a kernel density estimate for the distribution:

```
df = # dataset

# Histogram of sample distribution
hist(df)

# Add Kernel Density to the plot
lines(density(df))
```

To estimate the *population distribution* would require making certain assumptions about the sampling process. For instance, temperature datasets may have spatial-temporal dependency so you would need more robust standard errors for estimates of the population moments.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding the exercise, but It asks to compare the empirical distribution (through the histogram of the data) with the theoretical distribution on the same plot: so I need to plot a curve (a normal one, I guess) onto the histogram but I don't know what parameters I am supposed to use.

Comment: If you are willing to assume that the sampling process is i.i.d. (ignoring potential spatial-temporal bias in the process), then you can find the _sample_ statistics $\bar{x}, \bar{\sigma}^2$ and simply apply Bessel's Correction for the unbiased _population_ estimates - yielding the population distribution $\mathcal{N}(\bar{x}, \frac{N}{N-1}\bar{\sigma}^2)$.

Comment: Yes, we are dealing with casual samples (iid and independence) without any further assumptions. Just one more question: does the coefficient of the variance N/N-1 refer to the sample length (30/29 in my case)?

Comment: Yes $N$ is the sample size.